# How can I import special characters using Feeds?

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I am using the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module to import data into my site from a CSV file.

When I try to import a row that has the € character, nothing gets imported and I get an error message.

> error:General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE0 Cali...' for
>   column 'message' at row 1

How can I import special characters using Feeds?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> ... provides a small plugin architecture for Feeds to modify data before it gets saved. [Several plugins are available by default](https://www.drupal.org/node/1246578) and are described in the examples section below. Additional plugins can be added in separate modules or through the issue queue.

It allows for HTML encoding / decoding of feeds content before saving.

PS: Feeds Tamper doesn't know anything about taxonomy terms (you cannot use it for "Terms", as mentioned in a comment to this answer, which the original question didn't mention though).

Comment: I have term €/Kg.. still not working with feeds tamper module

Comment: its not wokring with importing taxonomy term.

Answer (score 0):

I had also problems importing special german and french characters with feeds.
The problem was solved this way:
- Open the CSV File in editor (e.g. pspad)
- Set Format to UTF 8
- Save

--> you have to do this even when it shows, that the format is UTF 8.

Maybe this helps?